# Proving a simple math inequality

Tags: inequality, examples-counterexamples

Let's say I have the following relations (all real numbers):

$$a_2 \leq a_1$$
$$x_1 \leq v_1$$
$$x_1 + x_2 \leq v_1 + v_2$$

How to show:
$$a_1x_1+a_2x_2 \leq a_1v_1 + a_2v_2$$

This can be shown intuitionally but I am unable to show this mathematically. What can be done to show this holds? NOTE: Please take care of negative values too.

Comment: The last result is still not correct

Comment: Seems $x_1,x_2,v_1,v_2$ are free to be positive or negative but we require another condition such as $0\le a_2\le a_1$ for this to be true, in general.

Comment: See my answer. You can have a weaker constraints than that.

Comment: On the LHS you need $a_2x_1 \dots$

Comment: I'm afraid you're right. Sorry. I'll fix it.

Comment: The current version is still false: What if $v_2=1$, $a_2=-1$, and $a_1=x_1=x_2=v_1=0$? Then the first three inequalities become $-1\le0$, $0\le0$, and $0\le1$. But the thing you want to show becomes $0+0\le0-1$, which is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's wrong.

Take $$(a_1,a_2,x_1,x_2,v_1,v_2)=(-2,-1,1,2,2,2).$$
We need to prove that:
$$-2\cdot1+(-1)\cdot2\leq-2\cdot2+(-1)\cdot2$$ or
$$-4\leq-6,$$ which is not true.

Your second problem is still wrong. Take: $$(a_2,a_1,x_1,x_2,v_1,v_2)=(-2,-1,1,2,2,2).$$

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong inequality. The first inequality will be reverse. Thnak you very much for pinting this out.

Comment: @DuttaA  You new problem is also wrong.

Comment: If we assume $a_1\ge a_2 \ge 0$, then it should work out.

Comment: @mjw  I think we don't need to create problems instead   topic-starter.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, Okay.  I like your approach, though.  A counter-example for each attempted problem formulation $\cdots$

Comment: Great answer. I think we can prove the inequality if $a_1 > 0$. else it will not be possible, what do you think?

Comment: @DuttaA, We need $a_2 \ge 0.$

Comment: Yes, we need it

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbf{a}=(a_1,a_2)^T$, $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2)^T$, $\mathbf{v}=(v_1,v_2)^T$ and $\mathbf{p}=(1,0)^T$, $\mathbf{q}=(1,1)^T$.

We have $$\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x} \le \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{v}$$ and
$$\mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{x} \le \mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{v}$$

we can find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so that $\mathbf{a}=\alpha\mathbf{p}+\beta\mathbf{q},$ namely $\alpha=a_1-a_2 \ge 0$ and $\beta=a_2$.

$$\alpha \ge 0 \Rightarrow$$ $$\alpha \,\mathbf{p}\cdot \mathbf{x} \le \alpha \,\mathbf{p}\cdot \mathbf{v} \phantom{12345}(*)$$

Now assume $\beta=a_2\ge 0:$

$$\beta \,\mathbf{q}\cdot \mathbf{x} \le \beta \,\mathbf{q}\cdot \mathbf{v} \phantom{12345}(**)$$

so, adding $(*)$ and $(**)$
$$( \alpha \mathbf{p} +\beta \mathbf{q} ) \cdot \mathbf{x} \le ( \alpha \mathbf{p}+\beta \mathbf{q}  ) \cdot \mathbf{v}$$
or
$$\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{x} \le \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{v}$$ which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: Please check the edited question. I am sorry I posted the wrong inequality.

Comment: Okay.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: p.x is not greater than p.v ....

Answer (score 0):

$$x_1 \leq v_1 \implies a_1x_1 \leq a_1v_1$$
$$a_2 \leq a_1 \implies a_2 x_2 \leq a_2v_2$$

Add these inequalities together.

Comment: What happens if $a_1<0$?

Comment: I assumed the scalars were positive.